# ReactJS, React-Router Getting previous path

Tags: animation, reactjs, css-transitions, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to make a single page application in which I have 3 components : **Index, BluePage and GreenPage**

I'm trying to use React and React router to switch through them. The layout is as follows:

This view is supposed to be like a sliding page and can be better visualized like this following diagram:

[image]

In order to do these transitions, I am currently using ReactCSSTransitionGroup and CSS classes, however it is becoming difficult as the direction the page must animate depends on the page that was being viewed before.

For example, if the BluePage was in view, and the user pressed the "back", button, the Index should move into view from the right.

On the other hand, if GreenPage was originally in view, the Index should move into view from the left.

### **The Question**

- How can I use React Router to send the existing path to the next component, so I can animate the components properly?
- Should I continue to use ReactCSSTransitionGroup or should I handle animations in the componentWillMount and componentWillUnmount callbacks?

  - If so, how does adding CSS classes to objects after initial rendering work?

---

I apologize if these questions seem somewhat novice - I am still a beginner to ReactJS. Thanks for all the help!

If any clarification is necessary, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check [`react-swipeable-views`](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views).

In this component, you just need to add all of your views (components) as children of the `SwipeableView` component. The currently active view is defined by `index` prop of the `SwipeableView`. You switch the view with buttons, you simply need to create a state in the main component (`App`, for example) and update this state in `onClick` handler. It would look like this:

```js
class MainComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
  }

  onBlueButtonClick() {
    this.setState({ index: 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={() => this.onBlueButtonClick()}>Click me!<div />
        <SwipeableView index={this.state.index}>
          <BlueView />
          <GreenView />
          <RedView />
        <SwipeableView />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps! ;)

**EDIT**: I have added a button in the example to explain how to use this component when there is no swipe effect. This is a React component and not a React Native, so it was made to work on a website, therefore without a swipe. I use it in one of my projects. Here's a [GIF](https://gyazo.com/70e2732d1c69cf36e7b489a3eeed1fb5) of it.

Comment: This won't exactly work, because I'm not looking for a touchscreen compatible kind of page swiper. The scenario I posted is just an example. In reality, the pages would move programmatically, and would be triggered by buttons on the screen. It's just another SPA but with some special CSS necessary.

Comment: It is possible to move with this component, while triggered by button. If you look at the doc, you can see why. Also, look at my example (look at the edit), as it is the basis of what you have to do to make it work,.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you is tu use [swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WP-bM1PyiAw). Why?

- performant (desktop, mobile)
- no jquery needed
- huge [api](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WP-cHVPyiAw), with very usefull features for your use case

  - change slide programmatically: `swiper.slideTo(2)` or `swiper.nextSlide()`)
  - `Hash/History Navigation`: sync between hash and slides
  - you can disable touch gestures
  - etc..

---

**Setup**

`npm install swiper --save`

**Import**

```
const Swiper = require('swiper');

or

import Swiper from 'swiper';
```

**Usage**

see [demos with example](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/)